# Is there a reason to run fillna() if there are no nan in the dataframe?

Tags: pandas, dataframe

So my dataframe is `frame` and there is `tz` column containing time zone information in string format.

```
clean_tz = frame['tz'].fillna('Missing')
```

If I know that all elements in `tz` column is in string format, although some maybe empty string or in incorrect format, is there a reason to run `fillna` since `fillna()` only checks for null or nan type?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a reason to run fillna() if there are no nan in the dataframe?

I think not, there is no reason.

> If I know that all elements in tz column is in string format, although some maybe empty string or in incorrect format, is there a reason to run fillna since fillna() only checks for null or nan type?

I think no, you can repalce empty strings like:

```
 frame['tz'] = frame['tz'].str.repalce(r'^\s*$', 'Missing')
```

But also is possible repalce values to NaNs and then use `fillna`, but obviously if not exist before in data in my opinion it is double replace - empty strings to NaNs and then NaNs to something else.